# Query string in URL makes main query misbehave and pagination not to work in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have archive page of movies in which I am presenting all movies paginated. On side bar I have genres(taxonomy) for movies. When user clicks on one I want results on the page to be filtered according to which genre he clicked.

My way of thinking made me do this using query string in URL. So when user click on genre it requests same URL (archive for movies) but adds `?genre=SOMETHING`. Then in `pre_get_posts` hook I have this if statement to modify main query:

```
if(
        !is_admin() &&
        $query->is_main_query() &&
        is_post_type_archive('movie') &&
        get_query_var('genre')
    )
```

Then after that I have code like this to filter movies by genre user clicked on :

```
$taxonomyQuery = [
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'genre',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => get_query_var('genre'),
                ],
            ];
$query->set('tax_query', $taxonomyQuery);
```

Sidebar link are constructed like this :

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url(add_query_arg('genre', $genre->slug)) ?>">
  <?php echo $genre->name; ?>
</a>
```

Taxonomy is created with name `genre` so that name is automatically added to `query_vars`.

When I open archive page of movies `/movies/` I get paginated results and everything works fine. But once I click on genre I get this path `/movies/?genre=comedy`.
`pre_get_posts` activates and filters movies according to the genre selected but pagination doesnt work. Even if I set `$query->set('posts_per_page', 1);` I still get more than one result returned from query. Problem only occurs when query string `?genre=SOMETHING` gets added to URL and I cannot figure out why.

NOTE: I am relatively new to wordpress development and I do not actually know if this is the right way to do this kind of thing.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So after some testing with different things I got to this conclusion.
When I registered taxonomy with register_taxonomy I did not place `'query_var'` property as I thought it is adding query string value like when you use :

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'demo_query_vars');
function demo_query_vars($queryVars) {
    $queryVars[] = 'genre';

    return $queryVars;
}
```

These two thing are not the same. First one enables you to load taxonomy using query_var. From the docs :

`` Sets the query var key for this taxonomy. Default `$taxonomy` key. If false, a taxonomy cannot be loaded at `?{query_var}={term_slug}`. If a string, the query `?{query_var}={term_slug}` will be valid. ``

Second one enables custom query_var and query string to be used, which is what i needed.

**FIX**: Just disable query_bar `'query_var' => false'`
Then add code I posted above to allow query variable to be processed (add_filter function) and you will be able to use your query_var.

**NOTE**: This problem was caused for me because I my taxonomy is called `genre` therfore query_var in register_taxonomy function is automatically set to this value. And I also wanted to use the same name for my own custom query_var which made conflicts.
**If your taxonomy name is different from your query_var (the query string you wich to use, example if I used `?g=SOMETHING` instead of `?genre=SOMETHING`) YOU WILL NOT run into this problem since there will be no conflicts between these two variables.**.

Another possible solution would be to make your custom query_var different than one specified in register_taxonomy if you are using query_var defined in register_taxonomy function. They just need to be different so there are no conflicts.

I am just at the beginning so this potentially could not be right but it for sure has something to do with these 2 variable names being the same.